# Como redirecionar para pasta da applicação?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

Uso o `ROR` com o `Nginx`.

Como faço para no que o `nginx` redirecione para a pasta da aplicação? Ao invés da pasta `/public`.

Answer (score 1):

Veja neste arquivo `nginx.conf` eu usei na produção: https://gist.github.com/awesome/8821551#file-nginx-conf-L108

```
location /images/ {
  root /var/www/shared/images;

  rewrite  ^/images/(.*)\.(.*)$  /$subdomain/$1.$2  break;
  rewrite  ^/images/(.*)\.(.*)$  /$subdomain/images/$1.$2  break;
  rewrite  ^/images/(.*)\.(.*)$  /$subdomain/images/original/$1.$2  break;

  # retornar arquivo específico quando nenhuma correspondência
  #error_page   404          /404.html;

  # retornar apenas
  return   403;
}
```